# how to remove wp-includes/css/classic-themes.min.css?

Tags: wordpress

after upgrade to wordpress 6.1, there is a new style link in head, the link is domain.com/https://www.example.com/wp-includes/css/classic-themes.min.css?ver=1, and the content is

```
/*! This file is auto-generated */
.wp-block-button__link{color:#fff;background-color:#32373c;border-radius:9999px;box-shadow:none;text-decoration:none;padding:calc(.667em + 2px) calc(1.333em + 2px);font-size:1.125em}
```

how to remove it? Thank you

i tried searched but there is no answer in google. maybe its a new question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check the source code of your website and get the id of that stylesheet. it may look like this.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='classic-theme-styles-css' href='https://example.com/wp-includes/css/classic-themes.min.css?ver=1' media='all' />
```

then your id will be `classic-theme-styles` and use wp_dequeue_style().

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mywptheme_child_deregister_styles', 20 );
function mywptheme_child_deregister_styles() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'classic-theme-styles' );

}
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/

Comment: Do you know how to disable the inline CSS in the editor as well? Dequeing works in frontend, but I still had to increase specifity to match my base styles in the Gutenberg interface.

Answer (score 2):

Since classic-themes.min.css file is enqueued via [wp_enqueue_classic_theme_styles()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_classic_theme_styles/) function in wp-includes/script-loader.php with classic-theme-styles handle

I'd use:

```
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_classic_theme_styles' );
```